# content of variable in string variable R studio

Tags: r, string, variables, numeric

I would to like ask You about using numerical variable in string vairable in R studio. for example:

```r
U<-mean(x)
H<-"Here exemplary text: [here use U] next text [here use U] text"
```

Thank You for help, and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: you can use `paste('some text:', U)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ways to approach this.

Say you are starting with:

```
x <- 1:5
U <- mean(x)
U

[1] 3
```

You can use the `glue` package:

```
H <- glue("Here exemplary text: {U} next text {U} text")
H

Here exemplary text: 3 next text 3 text
```

Or use `sprintf`:

```
H <- sprintf("Here exemplary text: %.2f next text %.2f text", U, U)
H

[1] "Here exemplary text: 3.00 next text 3.00 text"
```

Or (as suggested by @akrun), if the same value is repeated within the same character string, you could add `1$` within the format placeholders in `sprintf`:

```
H <- sprintf("Here exemplary text: %1$.2f next text %1$.2f text", U)
H

[1] "Here exemplary text: 3.00 next text 3.00 text"
```

Or use `paste`:

```
H <- paste("Here exemplary text:", U, "next text", U, "text")
H

[1] "Here exemplary text: 3 next text 3 text"
```

Comment: For `sprintf`, if the same input is repeated, can also use `$1` `sprintf("Here exemplary text: %1$.2f next text %1$.2f text", U)#
[1] "Here exemplary text: 3.00 next text 3.00 text"`